# Using a lookup list of lists to find values above thresholds in second list of lists and quantify them

Tags: r, list

I have a problem that is an extension of a question I asked earlier [Using a nested lookup table to find values above thresholds in second table and quantify them in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64583475/using-a-nested-lookup-table-to-find-values-above-thresholds-in-second-table-and) This time I have a list of list with data frames.
I’m analyzing river streamflow data with R language and I have two lists of lists. First holds data (Flowtest_all) from two different projections (Flowtest1 and Flowtest2) for different river reaches called numbers such as 910 and 950. I have hundreds of daily streamflow measurements (Flow).

```
Flowtest1 <- list("910" = tibble(Flow=c(123, 170, 187, 245, 679, 870, 820)),
                 "950" = tibble(Flow=c(570, 450, 780, 650, 230, 470, 340)))
Flowtest2 <- list("910" = tibble(Flow=c(167, 125, 287, 345, 570, 789, 825)),
                 "950" = tibble(Flow=c(573, 427, 717, 682, 237, 510, 376)))
Flowtest_all <- list(Flowtest1, Flowtest2)
```

Second list of lists called RCH_all serves as a lookup table, it also contains data from two different projections (RCH1 and RCH2). I calculated the value of the 0.75% percentile (Q3) on a different streamflow dataset than Flowtest_all (So I don’t want to use Q3 calculated for Flowtest_all). Analysed years and river reaches are the same in Flowtest_all and RCH_all.

```
RCH1 <- list("910" = data.frame( Q3=650),
                "950" = data.frame(Q3=550))
RCH2 <- list("910" = data.frame(Q3=670),
                "950" = data.frame(Q3= 570))
RCH_all <- list(RCH1, RCH2)
```

What I would like to obtain is the quantity of the Flow values from Flowtest_all which fall above the threshold specified in matching Q3 in RCH_all, per subbasin.
I want to obtain a result which looks like `Result_all <- list (Resulttest1, Resulttest2)`
Where:

```
Resulttest1 <- list("910" = data.frame( aboveQ3=3),
                  "950" = data.frame( aboveQ3=3))
Resulttest2 <- list("910" = data.frame( aboveQ3=2),
                  "950" = data.frame( aboveQ3=3))
```

I tried the code below but it’s producing an error:

```
test <- Map(function(x, y) aggregate( Flow > Q3, merge(x, y, all = TRUE, na.action = 'na.pass'), sum, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = 'na.pass'), Flowtest_all, RCH_all)
```

Error:

> Error in aggregate(Flow > Q3, merge(x, y, all = TRUE, na.action =
> "na.pass"), : object 'Flow' not found

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

While I do not fully grasp your requirement on the analytics side I would first of all do the following with your (example) data.

```
> library(dplyr) 
> FT <- bind_rows(list("Flowtest1" = bind_rows(Flowtest1, .id = "id"), 
                     "Flowtest2" = bind_rows(Flowtest2, .id = "id")), .id = "FlowTest") 

> head(FT)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  FlowTest  id     Flow
  <chr>     <chr> <dbl>
1 Flowtest1 910     123
2 Flowtest1 910     170
3 Flowtest1 910     187
4 Flowtest1 910     245
5 Flowtest1 910     679
6 Flowtest1 910     870
```

And as soon as the data ends up being in a tidy format that way, only then would I apply the necessary thresholds and look ups on the respective groups of data (defined by the cols "FlowTest" and "id").

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful! I feel more confident working with data frames than lists and I was able to work my way to the desired outcome.

Comment: @JoannaOK - you're welcome; my initial guess, that helping rearrange, the data you provided would benefit your later analysis, seemed right, same as my expectation that you are smart enough to take the final steps yourself ;-)